# Creating one list by combining two list in a list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

new to Python. Tried to find an answer but couldn't find anything or understand anything. I'm ok with for loops but I'm trying to combine two lists into one through a list comprehension. I'm fairly new to list comprehensions. So Something like:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['p','q','r','s','t','u']
```

I want an output that comes out like this:

```
list3 = ['ap','aq','ar','as','at','au','bp','bq','br','bs','bt','bu','cp','cq','cr','cs','ct','cu'...]
```

I didn't write the whole thing but I hope it gets the point across. How can I do this based solely on a list comprehension?

Comment: `[f + s for f in list1 for s in list2]`

Comment: `list(map(lambda t: ''.join(t), itertools.product(list1, list2)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = ['p','q','r','s','t','u']

result = [ a+b for a in list1 for b in list2 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate the desired output:

```py
from itertools import product

[''.join(item) for item in product(list1, list2)]
```

This outputs:

```py
['ap', 'aq', 'ar', 'as', 'at', 'au', 'bp', 'bq', 'br', 'bs', 'bt', 'bu', 'cp', 'cq', 'cr', 'cs', 'ct', 'cu']
```

Prefer this answer over ones that use multiple `for` clauses in a single list comprehension: [some](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#27-comprehensions--generator-expressions) consider it to be poor style.